# Login button navigates to another page even if wrong login credentials (stored in firebase firestore) are received

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, react-router, react-router-dom

I have created a login page with a login button. Now I want to make it such that whenever login button is clicked, it calls the authentication system of firebase and checks if the user exists, and if yes, navigate to the homepage. How can I make that?

I have set up the firestore, I just want to make it such that it navigates to another page only if the user exists, otherwise throw an error.

The login function of firebase looks like this

```
const logInWithEmailAndPassword = async (email, password) => {
  try {  
    await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    alert("Email or Password not Registered!");
  }
};
```

This is the login button

```
<button 
  onClick={async () => {
    await logInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    navigate('/Login/HomePage)};
  }}
>
  Login
</button>
```

Now no matter what the email and password is, it still navigates to the homepage.
How to do this setup so that it only navigates if and only if the user exists in firestore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The `logInWithEmailAndPassword` function is catching and swallowing any Promise rejections and thrown errors and so is effectively returning to the runtime scope of the `button` element's `onClick` callback which then issues the imperative navigation action.

## Solution

Return the Promise object from `signInWithEmailAndPassword` in `logInWithEmailAndPassword` and handle the happy/sad path in the `button` element's `onClick` handler.

Example:

```
const logInWithEmailAndPassword = async (email, password) => {
  return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
};
```

...

```
<button 
  onClick={async () => {
    try {
      await logInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      navigate("/Login/HomePage");
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error);
      alert("Email or Password not Registered!");
    }
  }}
>
  Login
</button>
```

### Alternative Solution

Alternatively you could pass the `navigate` function to `logInWithEmailAndPassword` and navigate when authenticated.

Example:

```
const logInWithEmailAndPassword = async (email, password, navigate, target = "/") => {
  try {  
    await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    navigate(target);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    alert("Email or Password not Registered!");
  }
};
```

...

```
<button 
  onClick={() => {
    logInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password, navigate, "/Login/HomePage");
  }}
>
  Login
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like that

```
const logInWithEmailAndPassword = async (email, password) => {
 try {  
  await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  navigate('/Login/HomePage');
 } catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
  alert("Email or Password not Registered!");
 }
};
```

Comment: Yes Thank you for this solution, but for this to happen, i would have to initiate a function component in firebase.js file, as hooks (useNavigate) can't be used without a function . Can you suggest another alternative

Comment: and then the function would have to return something, what should i code there